# Passing multiple arguments and result of last function through pipe

Tags: ramda.js

I'm building a pipe with Ramda.js which accepts three arguments. The first function needs those three arguments, and it's result is used in the second function. However, the second function also needs one of the initial arguments. I cannot figure out the branching to build something like it.

In pseudocode style, I need something like this:

```js
const composedFunction = R.pipe(
  firstFunction,
  secondFunction,
);

const firstFunction = (reusedArgument, secondArgument, thirdArgument) => someAnswer;
const secondFunction = (reusedArgument, someAnswer);

console.log(composedFunction({ foo: bar }, [5, 3, 4], [100, 12, 12]));
```

Comment: This comes at an interesting time when Ramda is looking at possible generic ways of doing this: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2930#issuecomment-562218926.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a few solutions:

Wrap your pipe inside another function so that functions in your composition can still refer to the original parameters.

Here `func2` accepts the output of `func1` but also has access to the initial `b` parameter. Obviously `func2` must be curried and be designed to accept its "data" as the last parameter (which is a tenet of Ramda and functional programming in general I'd say).

```js
const func3 = (a, b, c) =>
  pipe(func1, func2(b))
   (a, b, c);

func3(10, 20, 30);
```

Other option, `func1` returns an array which you can destructure in `func2`.

I don't think this is particularly nice but it is an option:

```js
const func1 = (a, b, c) => [a + c, b];
const func2 = ([sum, b]) => sum * b;

const func3 = pipe(func1, func2);
func3(10, 20, 30);
```

Comment: Your first solution worked exactly like I hoped, and seems really clean to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest thing here is to not bother with Ramda's `pipe` function, which is not designed to handle such case, and just write it manually:

```js
const func1 = (a, b, c) => `func1 (${a}, ${b}, ${c})`
const func2 = (a, d) => `func2 (${a}, ${d})`

const func3 = (a, b, c) => func2 (func1 (a, b, c), a)

console .log (func3 ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Ramda has recently been [considering a way](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2930#issuecomment-562218926) to make this easier for longer pipelines; even with that, though, the above is probably simpler for just a few functions.

Comment: You are probably right :) However, the pipe I am building is going to have a couple of more functions. The pipe is going to keep it readable, I hope...